# Positioning of graphviz nodes with Python

Tags: python, graphviz, dot

With this code:

```
from graphviz import Graph, Digraph
g = Digraph('G', filename='process.gv', engine='dot')

g.node('Tests')
g.node('Devices')

# Tests
g.edge('TestName', 'Tests')

# Devices
g.edge('Serial', 'Devices')

g.view()
```

I can create the following output:

[image]

But I need the field "Serial" below the field "Tests". How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with an invisible edge:

```
g.edge('Tests', 'Serial', style="invis")
```

[image]